# Customize close button of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I used [modal angular strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals) in controller, as the following:

```
$scope.modal = $modal({
   scope: $scope, 
   title: 'My Title', 
   content: text, 
   html: true, 
   contentTemplate: 'views/partials/myTemplate.html', 
   show: true, 
   keyboard: false, 
   backdrop: "static"
});
```

I need to customize the action of close button in the top of modal at the following image: 
[image: Modal Example].

How can I overwrite the close action of top button ?

Comment: if u not already much bounded to this library, better use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Not everyone is very fond of angularui for bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set a template for the modal, or give the modal an ID and use CSS.

```
<!-- You can use a custom html template with the `data-template` attr -->
<button ... data-template="modal/docs/modal.demo.tpl.html" ...
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" ng-show="title">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" ng-bind-html="title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" ng-show="content">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$hide()">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There you can customise the button how you would like. Alternitively a good way to just remove it without adding a new template would be to add an id to the modal and hide the close button with css.

Javascript

```
$scope.modal = $modal({
   ...
   id: 'noCloseButton'
});
```

CSS

```
#noCloseButton > .close { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your own template and leave out the `ng-click="$hide()"` on the button.

See link in docs under `template` option which would be used exactly the same way you are using `contentTemplate`